# Move named range data from one workbook to another

Tags: excel, vba

I have two identical workbooks where there are identical named ranges. In one of the workbooks (wbSource) those named ranges contain data and in the other workbook (wbTarget) the named ranges are empty. I am trying to come up with a solution for how to transfer the data in the named ranges from wbSource to wbTarget. I would appreciate if someone here can assist me with this. I tried using the code below but with no success.

```
Sub dataTransfer()

Dim targetModel, sourceModel, fileC As String
Dim rangesArray As Variant

targetModel = "Target.xlsm"
sourceModel = "Source.xlsm"
fileC = "C:\mypath\"

Dim wbSource As Workbook: Set wbSource = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=fileC & sourceModel)
Dim wbTarget As Workbook: Set wbTarget = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=fileC & targetModel)

rangesArray = Array("Coconut", "Apple", "Pear") 'An array of the names for the named ranges in both wbSource and wbTarget.

For Each element in rangesArray
 wbTarget.Range(element) = wbSource.Range(element)
Next element

End Sub
```

Comment: `Range` is a property of the `Worksheet` object, not `Workbook` so you need to add sheet references.

Comment: Thank you. I see it works when I refer to the worksheets instead.